# Как сделать так чтобы у персонажа временно переключалась анимация при столкновении с объектом?

Tags: unity3d, анимация

Казалось бы вроде бы просто всё но я не знаю как это сделать и нигде не могу найти как сделать так чтобы анимация переключалась во время столкновения с объектом

Уже весь инет перерыл... Ничего не нашел как это сделать Я только недавно начал пользоваться Юнити

Хочу чтобы когда предмет допустим кирпич попадает в ведро персонажа у персонажа менялась анимация

Кирпич называется brick как то так а помечен он как "bads"

Проблема в том что я не знаю как написать скрипт для смены анимации и на кого его повесить на кирпич или на персонажа

Скрипт сам удалился по непонятным причинам...

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

На ютубе есть полно видео по этой теме, думаю вам просто нужно разобраться как работать с аниматором. Вот видео https://youtu.be/Ohq8tgKpx1k